# Variation of geodesic and Jacobi field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was reading on Jacobi field of a geodesic, and noticed that given a geodesic $\gamma$ it is defined using the term of variation or family of geodesics $\gamma_s$ but never mentioned how to create such a family that admits the terms. 
I couldn't fin such an explanation in any book.

Comment: You can get families of geodesics using the exponential, what precisely is your question?